# FieldStorage is empty despite a GET request with fields

Tags: python, get, cgi

I am beginning with python CGI programming, using mod_python in apache2, and am trying to retrieve the GET fields in HTTP requests to a simple .py page.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                       

import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
print '''                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
'''
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
l = len(form.keys())
print "<p>%s field(s) set.</p>" % l
print '''                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
'''
```

The page prints "0 field(s) set." What could be wrong here? So far in my search for an answer I haven't find a parameter in mod_python of apache2 that would block the transmission of GET fields to the CGI script.

Comment: Can you show us the URL, to verify that you actually are passing fields properly?

Comment: I'm using URLs like myserverip/get.py?test=1

Comment: When I posted this it was more of a comment than an answer, so moving it here: "Have you configured `mod_python` with the [cgihandler](http://www.modpython.org/live/mod_python-3.2.8/doc-html/hand-cgi.html) in your Apache config?" OP's answer, in short: "Yes."

Answer (score 0):

cgi.FieldStorage relies on a multipart form being POSTed, not sent via GET.  Change the method on your form and make sure you have multipart in the form tags:

```
<form action="" method="post" multipart>
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you use the GET method, cgi.FieldStorage just grabs the query string, which will at best give you the name of the file you're trying to submit.

Comment: Mmmh. Doesn't seem to work either, the POST arguments disappear too. Is there something in the Apache or mod_python configuration that could cause this?

Comment: Anyway the various tutorials I found mention the possibility to get to GET fields from FieldStorage.